# Call inner-class method within Groovy script?

Tags: class, methods, groovy

I have been searching for an answer for something that seems so trivial...

Anyway, here's my code:

```
class Test {
   def done() {
      println("Well done, you've completed the test!")
   }
}

def test = new Test()
test.done()
```

Yet nothing is being printed.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. When I try to call the 'done' method within the inner-class Test it doesn't work (nothing is being printed).

Comment: How are you running it? This works for me no matter what I do. Please provide version. Als, I don't understand how your "clarification" differs from your question, nor why if you have additional information (little things like how you're running it, versions, etc) you wouldn't just edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

***Oh silly boo boo!***

I was parsing the script and not evaluating it which led to it not being executed properly...